# What's the simplest yet efficient way to check for duplicates in a realm Results<>?

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, realm

I'm trying to list contacts that a user can add to an event, but I want to filter the results so duplicates don't show up. So if I added John Doe his contact won't show up in the list of contacts. I'm not not well versed with NSPredicate so I'm not sure if that's the best way or to convert the Results array to something easier to work with.

Comment: why not save and update model with a primaryKey if you don't want duplicate results  ?

Comment: I converted my results to a set and then used `exclusiveOrInPlace` to removed a set of previous used contacts from the saved event. I have 3 sets of contacts to add, previous contacts, and one for the results. Should this be an efficiency concern?

Answer (score 0):

Here is example on kotlin, but very close to swift. 
You can do something like that. Instead of getting RealmResults you can get List of users that filtered by name.

```
fun filteredUsers(){
    val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
    realm.where(UserRealm::class.java)
        .findAllAsync()
        .asObservable()
        .filter { users -> users.isLoaded }
        .flatMap { users -> Observable.from(users) }
        .filter { user -> !user.name.equals("John Doe") }
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doOnError { err -> err.printStackTrace() }
        .toList()
        .subscribe { userList -> print(userList) }
}
```

And also I found in docs much easier way for swift:

```
// Query using a predicate string
var tanDogs = realm.objects(Dog).filter("color = 'tan' AND name   BEGINSWITH 'B'")

// Query using an NSPredicate
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "color = %@ AND name BEGINSWITH %@", "tan", "B")
tanDogs = realm.objects(Dog).filter(predicate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a distinct query, but [Realm doesn't support them natively yet](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1103).

You can however, get the data out of a Realm and do the deduplication yourself, but then you lose Realm's auto-updating `Results` type:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let currentUser = realm.objects(User).filter("me == true").first!
let uniqueContactNames = Set(currentUser.contacts.valueForKey("name") as! [String])
```

See [#1103](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1103) for more details and suggested workarounds.